# What does JDBC Connection really mean? Wanted to know internals of the same

Tags: java, jdbc

Is "opening the JDBC Connection" related to open a Socket with the DataBase software?

Comment: A JDBC Connection is usually a TCP/Socket connection to a database server.  The driver will communicate using a protocol specific to the database.  What sort of internals do you need to know?  The database does all the "interesting" work.

Comment: JDBC provides an abstract Java API for communicating with a database. Different JDBC adapters handle the actual database specific connection details.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. I agreed with your answer. So, JDBC Statement means writing SQL queries in the form of streams to the DB?

Comment: @RamBavireddi That is the basic idea.  Most likely a binary, rather than text protocol is used so that you don't get needless parsing errors e.g. text fields with a ' in them.

Comment: @Peter. Finally, I would like to know one thing. Does not Closing JDBC Connection close all other objects like ResultSet, Statement? Need help in getting this clear..

Comment: @RamBavireddi That depends on the driver.  It might not close the underlying connection, it might just return it to a pool to be reused when you ask for another one.

Comment: @Peter. I dont mean about Pooled connection object. I mean about a manually created connection object?

Comment: @RamBavireddi Can you give an example?  AFAIK, you can't create your own.

Comment: @Peter. Cant we create a Connection object using DriverManager.getConnection()?

Comment: @RamBavireddi You can but you have no idea whether it uses a pooled connection or not.

Answer (score 1):

Databases provides connections to client eg. a GUI Administrative tool to manage related database like SQLyog for MySQL and so in JDBC connection we are requesting a connection from our application as client through JDBC API.
These connection as TCP connections so a client is required to know the port no and ip of the database server to talk to it.

what you must be wondering at is what is JDBC? if so then

 JDBC is an **interface** provided by java that manages database operations and most awesome thing about this interface you will be writing exactly same code whether you are querying a MySQL or a PostgreSQL database servers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of JDBC driver you are using. According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity

you may have four types of JDBC drivers which usually (but not necessarily always) rely on TCP/Socket connections.

Answer (score 0):

A JDBC connection can actually be anything - it's a generic way to talk to databases.

In most cases it is a TCP/IP connection but that is not always the case. For example you can embed a Derby Databse within your Java application and talk directly to that without even leaving your process.

If you find out what your database and driver is that should allow you to answer your question.

Comment: We would use a combination of Type3 with Type4 driver and Oracle DB

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you require.[This](http://aspen.ucs.indiana.edu/webtech/jdbc/overviewpaper/JDBCconn.html) should answer all your queries. Cheers.